# Activity Navigation

Tags: android, navigation

I am new at creating android apps and I am trying to do something that seems like it should be simple but even after searching here I cannot seem to find a way to do what I want...

I have 2 activities (A and B).  Activity A has a navigation button that starts activity B, and activity B has a navigation button that starts activity A. Both are implemented with code like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

If I start my app and activity A is on the screen and I then press the back key, the app "goes away" just as I want.

So far, so good.

However, if I start my app, and use the navigation buttons to switch from A to B and then from B back to A and THEN press the back key, activity B appears.  What I want is that any time I press the back key from activity A, I want my app to "go away" just as it did when I had not yet navigated away from activity A.  Can that be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do that, do the following in your navigation button in ActivityB:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
intent.setFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

This makes your ActivityA instance came to the front instead of creating a new one. And by finishing the ActivityB the back button will make the app "go away".

Comment: That seems to do it.  Thanks!  Wish I could give you a +1 but I guess I'm too new.

Comment: No problem, but you can mark the answers as the correct one to help me!.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, A.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Comment: Just for my learning experience, what does Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK add to the previous answer?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

Answer (score 0):

Use Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP flag

```
Intent a = new Intent(this,ActivityA.class);
a.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(a);
```

Now whenever we go back to A, everything above A is cleared, setting it to the root activity again.

Good read 
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack.html